# how to have separate tomcat logs for a single war 

Tags: tomcat, logging

I am using a single war which is used in different way depending on the resources (ie. the URL by which it is called).

The resources are accessed from outside the webapps.

I need to maintain separate logs so that all the logs can be maintained separately.So i need to have a folder logs like the resources folder outside the webapps for this.

Comment: by default, `logs` folder is parallel to `webapps` in CATALINA_HOME. So why is anything special needed? It's already outside.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain different log for a single war file ?

Comment: Is it different based on some package name? or on what basis? Log4J can do this

Comment: yes it is different on the basis of url this war is made the docbase. So each of them require separate logs to be maintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there is a way to do this using log4j. I'm not saying this is the best way, but this method should work. Here's a starting point.

Download `log4j.jar` and put it in your `WEB-INF/lib`

Have a `log4j.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`. It will look like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n


log4j.logger.myoldsitelogger=DEBUG,myoldsite

# myoldsite writes to file
log4j.appender.myoldsite=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myoldsite.File=${catalina.base}/logs/tomcatlog4j.log
log4j.appender.myoldsite.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.myoldsite.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myoldsite.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n

log4j.logger.mynewsitelogger=DEBUG,mynewsite


# mynewsite writes to file
log4j.appender.mynewsite=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mynewsite.File=${catalina.base}/logs/tomcatlog4j_newsite.log
log4j.appender.mynewsite.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.mynewsite.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mynewsite.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n
```

Now from your app, get a handle to the right logger

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myoldsitelogger");
Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("mynewsitelogger");

if(request.getParameter("oldsite") != null)
    logger.info("In my.jsp from oldsite");
else
    logger2.info("In my.jsp from newsite");
```

In your logs folder, you should have the 2 log files named `tomcatlog4j.log` and `tomcatlog4j_newsite.log` with the right messages.

There could be a way to do this in Tomcat even without log4j, but I dont have a working sample yet